# using hidden elements in pages to store data

Tags: javascript, html

I need to store data in html documents that are associated with elements, and that I can get to with javascript.  I think I want to avoid arbitrary attributes on elements, since after reading various posts here I don't trust them.  I can't use id or class, since I those are used for other things and I don't want to mess with them (my project has to work on wide varieties of html so I can't make any assumptions as to the design of the class and id structure).  Another thing I need is for whatever I do, it needs to survive round-tripping through innerHTML (of a parent or ancestor element of the element I need to tag with data), with data intact.

I have considered various hidden elements (including script tags and html comments), which I insert into the document right before the element I need to tag with data.  Currently my favorite is hidden form elements (i.e. input with type "hidden").  I can stick any data I want into the "value" of the element, and I can find all such elements easily enough with getElementsByTagName().  Also importantly, it doesn't seem to affect the layout of the page.

I'm curious about the ramifications of this, and if anyone can think of any any problems with it.  I need to be able to put them anywhere in body of the page, before any element.  For instance I might need them associated with an option element (a child of a select element), so that rules out using a hidden div, since putting one of those inside a select element is illegal. I don't think they will affect form behavior, since they don't have a name attribute (I can avoid using id's if that helps).

Any thoughts on this, or suggestions for other ways of accomplishing the same that meets my needs?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this - what kind of data do you want to store in the page?

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  Also, why no attributes?  I have used attributes with my jQuery and they work fine...  I'm curious as to why you say that you don't trust them.

Comment: Just curious, but what sort of problems have you been reading about against using data-yourdataname="" attributes?  I use this method all the time with no issues, even to store long JSON strings.

Comment: One issue is they seem slower to access them if in a big document, because to my knowledge the only thing I can do is iterate through all elements to find them...at least with hidden form items i can use getElementsByTagName to narrow the number of elements to look at considerably.  But you may be right, I just got the impression they weren't widely supported or that the attributes might not survive round-tripping through innerHTML on some browsers, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Mark I've decided to go with your suggestion rather than hidden input elements, it looks like it will work even on ie6, and is html 5 compatible as long as it starts with "data-".  Feel free to make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is going to be data for JavaScript's purposes, why even try to put it in the HTML at all?  Here's a simple example of what I mean

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var nodeData = {
    foo: {/* Data to associate with div#foo */}
  , bar: {/* Data to associate with div#bar */}
};

</script>


<div id="foo">Foo!</div>
<div id="bar">Bar!</div>
```

It's simple and elegant since the principle of IDs being unique per document nicely matches with javascript's dictionaries requiring unique keys per entry.

Comment: because, as i said, i can't use id's since this has to work on pages where id's are used for other things and I can't redesign the id structure.  (for what it's worth, i am building a tool used for web development, so these things will not be in the "final" production pages....they will only be in pages used during the development process by designers, translators, php and js developers etc)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry.  I didn't quite understand all your requirements so I took a rough swag at it.  How about comment nodes?

Comment: Comment nodes are something else I've considered.  I'm not sure how to add them via javascript but I assume it is possible.  I also assume they are going to be in the innerHTML string of their parent